# to_date not validating user input value while creating view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, to-date

I am creating one View in Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 and I am adding following condition in my View:

```
WHERE trunc(whenmodified) = TO_DATE('&userinput', 'DDMMYYYY')
```

whenmodified is of date type.

I was expecting to get an error when user input is not in 'DDMMYYYY' format.
But there is no error for input like **14142020** and view is getting created.
I was expecting the following error:
ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am using SQL DEVELOPER for it.

Comment: A view doesn't have parameters. The ampersand has nothing to do with Oracle SQL. It is a means of your tool to replace values on the-fly. What Oracle sees is the already replaced string hence. You could add a virtual column `user_formatted_date generate always as to_char(whenmodified, 'DDMMYYYY')` to your table instead, if you want to ease writing queries with `where user_formatted_date = :userinput`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date you enter is not validated upon DDL, but upon a select from that view:

```
SQL> create or replace view td as select sysdate sd,dummy from dual where trunc(sysdate)=to_date('&az','ddmmyyyy');
Enter value for az: 12131444
old   1: create or replace view td as select sysdate sd,dummy from dual where trunc(sysdate)=to_date('&az','ddmmyyyy')
new   1: create or replace view td as select sysdate sd,dummy from dual where trunc(sysdate)=to_date('12131444','ddmmyyyy')

View created.

SQL> select * from td;
select * from td
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> set long 2000
SQL> select text from user_views where view_name='TD';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select sysdate sd,dummy from dual where trunc(sysdate)=to_date('12131444','ddmmyyyy')
```

As you can see the text of the view is taken as is, no validation. Validation is done when the view is used.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is - in my opinion - wrong. Create view *as is*, without such a condition. Then, if you want to restrict rows returned while selecting from that view, include it into `select`'s `where` clause. For example:

```
create or replace view v_test as
select whatever
from your_table;

select * From v_test
where trunc(whenmodified) = some_date
```

Besides, what benefit do you expect from letting users create a view? It is *you* who should do it, once, and let users *use* the view.